# How do I pre-populate a react-select multi dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-select

I have a modal that is used to update a users information. A component of this allows the user to select one or more clubs to be apart of. Thus, when they open the update modal I want to have the dropdown pre-populated with their current selections which are being persisted in the database as an array of string values. This way the user can see what they currently have and not have to reselect options they've previously selected. My current implementation is shown below:

```
import Select, { ActionMeta, MultiValue } from "react-select";
import classNames from "classnames";
import { selectStyling } from "../../utilities/SelectStyling";

export interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface Props {
  paddingTop?: string;
  paddingBottom?: string;
  title: string;
  options: Option[];
  placeholder: string;
  changeHandler: (newValue: Option[], actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => void;
  initialValues?: string[];
}

const FormMultiSelectDropdown = ({paddingTop, paddingBottom, title, options, placeholder, changeHandler, initialValues}: Props) => {

  const handleChange = (newValue: Option[] | MultiValue<Option>, actionMeta: ActionMeta<Option>) => {
    changeHandler(newValue as Option[], actionMeta);
  }

  const values: Option[] = [];

  if(initialValues) {
    initialValues.forEach((value) => {
      values.push({value: value.toLowerCase(), label: value})
    }); 
  }

  return(
    <div className={classNames('flex', 'flex-col', 'px-10', paddingTop, paddingBottom, 'font-bold')} >
      <label className="text-lg font-bold mb-2 text-orange-400">{title}</label>
      <Select
        value={values}
        onChange={handleChange}
        placeholder = {placeholder}
        options={options}
        styles={selectStyling}
        isMulti
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormMultiSelectDropdown;
```

*Note: this is supposed to be a reusable component as I have another similar implementation with coaches that the user can select*

This current implementation almost works. The dropdown is prepopulated with the array of values which is created by looping through the array of strings and pushing to an array that accepts type Option where Option looks like:

```
interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}
```

The problem I am facing is that by implementing it this way, the pre-populated values are not removable (i.e. when the 'x' is clicked they do not get removed). Furthermore, when I select a new value from the dropdown, it is not added to the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I handled the creation of `initialValues` as an `Option[]` from strings outside my multi select component.
Then inside my custom reusable select component, I use react hooks `useState` and `useEffect` to create and modify the `value` props of react-select.

```
export default function AppMultiSelect({
  onChange,
  options,
  value: valueProp,
}: AppMultiSelectProps) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(valueProp)

  useEffect(() => {
    setValue(valueProp)
  }, [valueProp])

  return (
      <Select
        isClearable
        isMulti
        options={options}
        onChange={onChange}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

And when I import this component in my code:

```
  //...
  // created initialOptions from my string array of pre-populated options
  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState(initialOptions) 

  //...
  // in returned JSX:
        <AppMultiSelect
          options={options}
          value={selectedOptions}
          onChange={(newValue: readonly Option[]) => setSelectedOptions([...newValue])}
        />
```